# Potentially ambiguous matrix index representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is probably a silly question, but I haven't come across an explanation yet.

When giving examples of matrices and other situations where a family of values $a$ exists in a two-dimensional framework (e.g. coefficients in a system of equations) I've often come across a representation like so: $a_{ij}$, with examples such as $a_{12}$, $a_{13}$, etc.

These examples never cover situations where the reference could be ambiguous, such as $a_{121}$, where it's not clear if $i=12$, $j=1$ or $i=1$, $j=21$. (Of course, this assumes that there are at least 21 columns and 12 rows so that the reference is truly ambiguous)

My question is if there's a different way of representing entries of this sort that can extend unambiguously to 2-digit (or more) values in either dimension.

Comment: In such a situation, one would just include a comma, like $a_{12,1}$ for the entry in row 12, column 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commas are generally inserted if the indices are unclear.
That is, the element in the 12th row and 1st column would be $$a_{12,1},$$
while the element in the 1st row and 21st column would be $$a_{1,21}.$$
Elements could also be denoted by something like $a_{ij} = A(i,j)$. So $a_{12,1} = A(12,1)$.

Any similarly clear notation can be used – essentially, the goal is to insert some separator element between the indices.